# jQuery ajax relative path not finding file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some script that I wrote in a HTML document but I decided to move it to an external file, so I changed the path that is in the jQuery to reflect the js file location but it doesn't seem to be able to find the PHP file it needs. Does anyone understand why this might be?

**jQuery**

```
function login(){
    var u = $("#loginUsername").val;
    var p = $("#loginPassword").val;
    if (u === ""){
        loginStatus("empty","username");
    } else if (p === ""){
        loginStatus("empty","password");
    } else {
        $("#loginbtn").css("display","none");
        $("#loginStatus").html("please wait...");
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "../../php/login.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) === true) {
                if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                    $("#loginStatus").html("Login failed. Please try agian");
                    $("#loginbtn").css("display","inline-block");
                } else if (ajax.responseText == "login_failed_1"){
                    loginStatus("wrong","password");
                } else {
                    window.location = "http://domain.com/"+ajax.responseText;
                }
            } else {
                $("#loginStatus").html("fail_667389");
            }
        };
        ajax.send("u="+u+"&p="+p);
    }
}
```

**File Hierarchy**

The PHP file is in the PHP folder and the JS files is in loginScripts.

Comment: Can you also illustrate your project `file` hierarchy

Comment: Please paste exact error message.

Comment: There are no errors. The code just stops executing at var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "../../php/login.php");

Comment: I have added the file hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

You trying to access a server file with a relative path ???

You have to use something like 'http://domain.com/php.login.php'